# Regex match values of CSS 'translate(0px, 0px)' off element style

Tags: javascript, css, regex, match, translate

Given a style attribute string, I need to capture the x and y values of a CSS `translate()` property. Numbers may be zero, positive or negative, float or integer, and only of pixel units.

A practical style attribute string example:

```
min-height: 100%;
min-width: 100%;
transition-property: transform;
transform-origin: 0px 0px;
transform: translate(123px, 0px) translateZ(0px);
```

I have a working, albeit *very* ugly solution. Here's a breakdown:

`var transform = element.style['transform']` - `transform` variable then contains this string: `"translate(123px, 0px) translateZ(0px)"`

Then I match it against:

```
transform = transform.match(/translate\(-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]*)?px, -?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]*)?px\)/);
```

I do this so if there's another transform property, like `rotate(20px, 20px)` for example, I can avoid it.

The regex produces this array: `["translate(123px, 0px)", undefined, undefined]`.

Another regex is then in order, to match the numeric values only:

```
transform = transform[0].match(/(-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]*)?)px, (-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]*)?)px/);
```

Then I am left with the following array: `["123px, 0px", "123", undefined, "0", undefined]`

And to finish everything I need to `parseInt(transform[1])` and `parseInt(transform[3])` to actually work with the values.

This seems like too much work for getting only those two numbers, but I am not very experienced with regular expressions, and I do not know how to streamline this. Is there a more elegant solution to this?

EDIT: I will particularly be happy to turn it all into a single regular expression :)

Comment: If you're doing a transition of some sort, it's better to store this data in variables rather than parse it every time. What are you trying to do?

Comment: That's true - however I am interacting with a script that doesn't have this implemented and I'm trying to save time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine the two steps into one by doing something like the following:

```
transform = transform.match(/translate\((-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?)px, (-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?)px\)/);
```

or if you trust your input you can do:

```
transform = transform.match(/translate\((.*)px, (.*)px\)/);
```

to simplify your regex.

Comment: What if I would still like to keep the regex as accurate as possible? I mean, what if you can't trust the input?

Comment: Then the first option is what you are looking for

Answer (score 3):

You can mark groups as non-capture `(?:.)` won't act as a capture, but otherwise behaves normally. And `\d` is the same as `[0-9]`. But also because this must be valid CSS anyway, you can presume that the data will be a valid integer/float anyway, and don't have to do the optional captures (if you don't want).

I'd do:

```
transform = transform[0].match(/(-?[.\d]+)px, (-?[.\d]+)px/);
```

Or, with non-capturing groups for an optional decimal point:

```
transform = transform[0].match(/(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)px, (-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)px/);
```

Comment: Fantastic! I am loving this. By "the optional captures" do you mean all this `-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]*)?`?

Comment: @pilau An optional capture is `(.)?` as the whole capture becomes optional. If that capture is within another and doesn't need to be a capture, you can use `(.(?:.)?)` which makes the inner group non-capturing and optional both.

Comment: Yeah OK, just wasn't sure what you were referring to

Comment: This should be the selected answer.